# Git update .gitignore without deleting files when merging or pushing

Tags: git, caching, indexing, delete-file

/rant/ this is driving me nuts. there are 1000s of questions about 'such' problems on SO, but none seem to provide a working answer. So bear with me.

I have a polluted working tree. I've written a huge .gitignore file that allows some things and not others. I can rebuild the repository with that new file. 
Now I want to push that .gitgnore file through the working flow - other branches, other remotes. But I can't get it done without git deleting files (in the working space) that were removed from the repository by the .gitignore file.

Take a folder structure

```
$ git ls-files
aa/11/file
aa/22/file
bb/11/file
bb/22/file
```

I want to add bb/22/* to .gitignore , and make git forget everything in that dir. For testing I try this in two branches

```
$ git checkout -b cleanup1
$ git checkout -b cleanup2
```

Rebuild the repository

```
$ nano .gitignore # (adding bb/22/*)
$ git rm -r cached
$ git add .
```

That seems to work fine:

```
$ git ls-files
.gitignore
aa/11/file
aa/22/file
bb/11/file

$ ls bb/22
file
```

But if I commit, checkout cleanup1, and merge cleanup2 with cleanup1, the file bb/22/* is deleted !

```
File .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG saved
[cleanup2 c4f7bfe] icleanup
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore
 delete mode 100644 bb/22/file

$ git checkout cleanup1
Switched to branch 'cleanup1'

$ ls bb
11  22

$ git merge cleanup2 
Updating b1d4f3a..c4f7bfe
Fast-forward
 .gitignore |    1 +
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore
 delete mode 100644 bb/22/file

$ ls bb
11
```

---

If I instead only commit the new .gitignore file, without rebuilding the repository, to all branches, and manually rebuild the repository on all branches, I can merge and push without problems:

(first go back)

```
git checkout cleanup1
git log # (find the last good commit)
git reset --hard b1d4f3aa5ba1fb1b28c288de823aabb2907bc774
git checkout cleanup2
git log # (find the last good commit)
git reset --hard b1d4f3aa5ba1fb1b28c288de823aabb2907bc774
```

now add a .gitignore

```
nano .gitignore 
git add .gitignore
git commit
git checkout cleanup1
git merge cleanup2
```

rebuilding the repositories manually on both ends

```
git checkout cleanup2
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
# do NOT commit
git checkout cleanup1
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
# do NOT commit
```

now go back and commit everything

```
git checkout cleanup2
git commit
git checkout cleanup1
git commit
```

and I can merge

```
$ git merge cleanup2
$ git ls-files
.gitignore
aa/11/file
aa/22/file
bb/11/file
$ ls bb/22
file
```

That means I have to push the .gitignore file everywhere, then call everyone to tell them to update all their branches and rebuild the repository manually on all their branches, make sure NOT to commit their changes, and when they're done, commit the branches one by one, but NOT push it any remote. When they are all done, I can update my repository and push that to the remotes.

Eh, that is weird.

So, what am I missing ? How to remove files from the index, without removing them from the working tree, in any branch and on any remote ?

Comment: Don't let the name of the "cache" fool you.  It's not that you need to clear some *cache* - as if it's out of date and harmless, you need to delete the files from the repository.  `.gitignore` applies only to the files that don't exist in the repository.  If you're asking for git to ignore changes to files *that exist in the repository* - and not to ignore new files - then it won't do that.

Comment: You're right, replaced the word cache everywhere.

Comment: I'm asking git to delete files from the repository, and leave them intact on the filesystem, on all branches and remotes.

Answer (score 0):

Right after I did all that on my repo, I thought of another trick would *probably* work:

- create a `backup` branch containing the version of the untracked files you want to keep
- create a `cleanup` branch and check it out
- rebuild your repository using the updated .gitignore
- go and checkout your other branches. you will probably have to use --force, but thats ok

for each branch

- merge it with the `cleanup` branch. this will delete all the files that you only wanted to ignore
- check into your backup branch (again with --force). this will restore the files that were just deleted.
- check back into the branch you were cleaning up. the restored files should be ignored

same before you pull: create a backup branch, pull - this will delete the files - checkout your backup branch, this will restore the files, checkout the original branch, files are now ignored.

**havent tested this !**